# How Flutter layout UI widget

Tags: flutter

Does Flutter calculte widget layout (size and position) in background thread then update in main thread ?

Like Facebook paper, it make UI/UX better.

Comment: no, flutter app is [single thread only](https://medium.com/globant/single-thread-dart-what-ccbca2543ae9)

Comment: dart can one single thread, but layout engine in flutter sdk can be another thread ?

Comment: no,there is no other thread

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY this is a first video of a nice series to learn more about asynchronous coding in Dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [Flutter architectural overview](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview#rendering-and-layout), there are 7 phases in the rendering pipeline:

[image: Flutter rendering phases]

The Build, Layout and Paint phases depend on the result of the previous, so they can't be parallelized or processed in a background thread.

Rasterization is the only phase run in a separate thread asynchronously, [using DevTools](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/performance) you can see how the UI and Raster threads work in parallel:

[image: DevTools performance timeline]